# How to add Child View Controller to TableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to add a Child View Controller to a Table View Controller and I added the same child to a regular UIViewController and it worked. I used essentially the same code for the UITableViewController however, and the view shows up in the top left corner of the screen. The code for the implementation of the child and the creation of the child view controller is below.
*Additionally, there is a UIButton that is supposed to remove the child from the parent and that is also not working.

Implementation of Child (UIViewController) in Parent (UITableViewController)-

```
func setupNavBar() {
        navigationItem.title = "Select Paper Item"
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "QuestionIcon"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleQuestion))
    }
    @objc func handleQuestion() {
        addChild(questionView)
        view.addSubview(questionView.view)
        questionView.didMove(toParent: self)
        view.addSubview(dismissQuestionView)
        dismissQuestionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        dismissQuestionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        dismissQuestionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        dismissQuestionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 80).isActive = true
        dismissQuestionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        dismissQuestionView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleDismissQuestionView), for: .touchUpInside)

        questionView.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        questionView.view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        questionView.view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        questionView.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 80).isActive = true
        questionView.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        questionView.answer.text = "Recycling is very important, however we must ensure that we are recycling properly. This is because throwing trash in the recycling bin can not only cause recycling facilities to spend unnecesary money, but can also cause items that are recyclable to be thrown in the trash. To make matters worse, every recycling facility has different guidelines for what materials they accept and don't accept. You can look up where different items should go on this page. The first way is to click the magnifying glass on the right which will allow you to automatically search for items by simply typing their name. The second way is search manually by first selecting the material of the item on this page."
    }
    @objc func handleDismissQuestionView() {
        questionView.willMove(toParent: nil)
        questionView.view.removeFromSuperview()
        questionView.removeFromParent()
        dismissQuestionView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
```

Creation of Child-

```
import UIKit

class QuestionView: UIViewController {

    let answer = UITextView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.7)
        setupAnswer()
    }

    func setupAnswer() {
        answer.backgroundColor = .white
        answer.textColor = .black
        answer.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        answer.font = UIFont(name: "AlNile", size: 14)
        view.addSubview(answer)
        positionAnswer()
    }
    func positionAnswer() {
        answer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        answer.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        answer.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        answer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
        answer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Entire View Controller with extensions-

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseStorage

class PaperMaterial: UIViewController {

    var rowHeight: CGFloat = 100
    var headerheight: CGFloat = 150

    let questionView = QuestionView()
    let dismissQuestionView = UIButton()

    let tableView = UITableView()

    var alphaHeaderArray = [AlphaHeader]()
    var aData = [CellData]()
    var bData = [CellData]()
    var cData = [CellData]()
    var dData = [CellData]()
    var eData = [CellData]()
    var fData = [CellData]()
    var gData = [CellData]()
    var hData = [CellData]()
    var iData = [CellData]()
    var jData = [CellData]()
    var kData = [CellData]()
    var lData = [CellData]()
    var mData = [CellData]()
    var nData = [CellData]()
    var oData = [CellData]()
    var pData = [CellData]()
    var qData = [CellData]()
    var rData = [CellData]()
    var sData = [CellData]()
    var tData = [CellData]()
    var uData = [CellData]()
    var vData = [CellData]()
    var wData = [CellData]()
    var xData = [CellData]()
    var yData = [CellData]()
    var zData = [CellData]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        setupNavBar()
        let db = Firestore.firestore()

        alphaHeaderArray =
            [AlphaHeader.init(label: "A"), AlphaHeader.init(label: "B"),
             AlphaHeader.init(label: "C"), AlphaHeader.init(label: "D"),
             AlphaHeader.init(label: "E"), AlphaHeader.init(label: "F"),
             AlphaHeader.init(label: "G"), AlphaHeader.init(label: "H"),
             AlphaHeader.init(label: "I"), AlphaHeader.init(label: "J"),
             AlphaHeader.init(label: "K"), AlphaHeader.init(label: "L"),
             AlphaHeader.init(label: "M"), AlphaHeader.init(label: "N"),
             AlphaHeader.init(label: "O"), AlphaHeader.init(label: "P"),
             AlphaHeader.init(label: "Q"), AlphaHeader.init(label: "R"),
             AlphaHeader.init(label: "S"), AlphaHeader.init(label: "T"),
             AlphaHeader.init(label: "U"), AlphaHeader.init(label: "V"),
             AlphaHeader.init(label: "W"), AlphaHeader.init(label: "X"),
             AlphaHeader.init(label: "Y"), AlphaHeader.init(label: "Z")]


        db.collection("paper").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                return
            }
            else {
                for document in snapshot!.documents {

                    let databaseData = document.data()
                    let name = databaseData["name"] as? String ?? ""
                    let category = databaseData["category"] as? String ?? ""
                    let firstLetter = name.prefix(1)
                    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
                    let imageRef = storageRef.child("Paper/\(name).jpg")
                    imageRef.getData(maxSize: 50 * 1024) { data, error in

                        if let error = error {
                            print(error)
                            return
                        }
                        else {
                            let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                            if firstLetter == "A" {
                                self.aData += [CellData.init(image: image, message: name, category: category)]
                            }
                            else if firstLetter == "B" {

                                self.bData += [CellData.init(image: image, message: name, category: category)]
                            }
                            else if firstLetter == "C" {
                                self.cData += [CellData.init(image: image, message: name, category: category)]
                            }
                            else if firstLetter == "D" {
                                self.dData += [CellData.init(image: image, message: name, category: category)]
                            }
                            else if firstLetter == "E" {
                                self.eData += [CellData.init(image: image, message: name, category: category)]
                            }
                            else if firstLetter == "F" {
                                self.fData += [CellData.init(image: image, message: name, category: category)]
                            }
                            else if firstLetter == "G" {
                                self.gData += [CellData.init(image: image, message: name, category: category)]
                            }
                            else if firstLetter == "H" {
                                self.hData += [CellData.init(image: image, message: name, category: category)]
                            }
                            else if firstLetter == "I" {
                                self.iData += [CellData.init(image: image, message: name, category: category)]
                            }
                            else if firstLetter == "J" {
                                self.jData += [CellData.init(image: image, message: name, category: category)]
                            }
                            else if firstLetter == "K" {
                                self.kData += [CellData.init(image: image, message: name, category: category)]
                            }
                            else if firstLetter == "L" {
                                self.lData += [CellData.init(image: image, message: name, category: category)]
                            }
                            else if firstLetter == "M" {
                                self.mData += [CellData.init(image: image, message: name, category: category)]
                            }
                            else if firstLetter == "N" {
                                self.nData += [CellData.init(image: image, message: name, category: category)]
                            }
                            else if firstLetter == "O" {
                                self.oData += [CellData.init(image: image, message: name, category: category)]
                            }
                            else if firstLetter == "P" {
                                self.pData += [CellData.init(image: image, message: name, category: category)]
                            }
                            else if firstLetter == "Q" {
                                self.qData += [CellData.init(image: image, message: name, category: category)]
                            }
                            else if firstLetter == "R" {
                                self.rData += [CellData.init(image: image, message: name, category: category)]
                            }
                            else if firstLetter == "S" {
                                self.sData += [CellData.init(image: image, message: name, category: category)]
                            }
                            else if firstLetter == "T" {
                                self.tData += [CellData.init(image: image, message: name, category: category)]
                            }
                            else if firstLetter == "U" {
                                self.uData += [CellData.init(image: image, message: name, category: category)]
                            }
                            else if firstLetter == "V" {
                                self.vData += [CellData.init(image: image, message: name, category: category)]
                            }
                            else if firstLetter == "W" {
                                self.wData += [CellData.init(image: image, message: name, category: category)]
                            }
                            else if firstLetter == "X" {
                                self.xData += [CellData.init(image: image, message: name, category: category)]
                            }
                            else if firstLetter == "Y" {
                                self.yData += [CellData.init(image: image, message: name, category: category)]
                            }
                            else {
                                self.zData += [CellData.init(image: image, message: name, category: category)]
                            }
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        self.tableView.register(ItemCustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "custom")
        positionTableView()
    }

    func setupNavBar() {
        navigationItem.title = "Select Paper Item"
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "QuestionIcon"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleQuestion))
    }
    @objc func handleQuestion() {
        addChild(questionView)
        view.addSubview(questionView.view)
        questionView.didMove(toParent: self)
        view.addSubview(dismissQuestionView)
        dismissQuestionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        dismissQuestionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        dismissQuestionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        dismissQuestionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 80).isActive = true
        dismissQuestionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        dismissQuestionView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleDismissQuestionView), for: .touchUpInside)

        questionView.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        questionView.view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        questionView.view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        questionView.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 80).isActive = true
        questionView.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        questionView.answer.text = "Recycling is very important, however we must ensure that we are recycling properly. This is because throwing trash in the recycling bin can not only cause recycling facilities to spend unnecesary money, but can also cause items that are recyclable to be thrown in the trash. To make matters worse, every recycling facility has different guidelines for what materials they accept and don't accept. You can look up where different items should go on this page. The first way is to click the magnifying glass on the right which will allow you to automatically search for items by simply typing their name. The second way is search manually by first selecting the material of the item on this page."
    }
    @objc func handleDismissQuestionView() {
        questionView.willMove(toParent: nil)
        questionView.view.removeFromSuperview()
        questionView.removeFromParent()
        dismissQuestionView.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    func positionTableView() {
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 80).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}

extension PaperMaterial: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vc = ObjectInfo()
        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            let data = aData[indexPath.row]
            vc.name = data.message
            vc.objImage = data.image
        case 1:
            let data = bData[indexPath.row]
            vc.name = data.message
            vc.objImage = data.image
        case 2:
            let data = cData[indexPath.row]
            vc.name = data.message
            vc.objImage = data.image
        case 3:
            let data = dData[indexPath.row]
            vc.name = data.message
            vc.objImage = data.image
        case 4:
            let data = eData[indexPath.row]
            vc.name = data.message
            vc.objImage = data.image
        case 5:
            let data = fData[indexPath.row]
            vc.name = data.message
            vc.objImage = data.image
        case 6:
            let data = gData[indexPath.row]
            vc.name = data.message
            vc.objImage = data.image
        case 7:
            let data = hData[indexPath.row]
            vc.name = data.message
            vc.objImage = data.image
        case 8:
            let data = iData[indexPath.row]
            vc.name = data.message
            vc.objImage = data.image
        case 9:
            let data = jData[indexPath.row]
            vc.name = data.message
            vc.objImage = data.image
        case 10:
            let data = kData[indexPath.row]
            vc.name = data.message
            vc.objImage = data.image
        case 11:
            let data = lData[indexPath.row]
            vc.name = data.message
            vc.objImage = data.image
        case 12:
            let data = mData[indexPath.row]
            vc.name = data.message
            vc.objImage = data.image
        case 13:
            let data = nData[indexPath.row]
            vc.name = data.message
            vc.objImage = data.image
        case 14:
            let data = oData[indexPath.row]
            vc.name = data.message
            vc.objImage = data.image
        case 15:
            let data = pData[indexPath.row]
            vc.name = data.message
            vc.objImage = data.image
        case 16:
            let data = qData[indexPath.row]
            vc.name = data.message
            vc.objImage = data.image
        case 17:
            let data = rData[indexPath.row]
            vc.name = data.message
            vc.objImage = data.image
        case 18:
            let data = sData[indexPath.row]
            vc.name = data.message
            vc.objImage = data.image
        case 19:
            let data = tData[indexPath.row]
            vc.name = data.message
            vc.objImage = data.image
        case 20:
            let data = uData[indexPath.row]
            vc.name = data.message
            vc.objImage = data.image
        case 21:
            let data = vData[indexPath.row]
            vc.name = data.message
            vc.objImage = data.image
        case 22:
            let data = wData[indexPath.row]
            vc.name = data.message
            vc.objImage = data.image
        case 23:
            let data = xData[indexPath.row]
            vc.name = data.message
            vc.objImage = data.image
        case 24:
            let data = yData[indexPath.row]
            vc.name = data.message
            vc.objImage = data.image
        default:
            let data = zData[indexPath.row]
            vc.name = data.message
            vc.objImage = data.image
        }

        vc.category = "paper"
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let alphaHeader = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("AlphaHeaderView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! AlphaHeaderView

        alphaHeader.headerLabel.text = alphaHeaderArray[section].label
        return alphaHeader
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return headerheight
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "custom") as! ItemCustomCell
        cell.messageView.font = UIFont(name: "ChalkboardSE-Bold",size: 20.0)
        cell.messageView.textColor = .black
        cell.itemImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.leftAnchor, constant: 75).isActive = true
        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            cell.itemImage = aData[indexPath.row].image
            cell.message = aData[indexPath.row].message
        case 1:
            cell.itemImage = bData[indexPath.row].image
            cell.message = bData[indexPath.row].message
        case 2:
            cell.itemImage = cData[indexPath.row].image
            cell.message = cData[indexPath.row].message
        case 3:
            cell.itemImage = dData[indexPath.row].image
            cell.message = dData[indexPath.row].message
        case 4:
            cell.itemImage = eData[indexPath.row].image
            cell.message = eData[indexPath.row].message
        case 5:
            cell.itemImage = fData[indexPath.row].image
            cell.message = fData[indexPath.row].message
        case 6:
            cell.itemImage = gData[indexPath.row].image
            cell.message = gData[indexPath.row].message
        case 7:
            cell.itemImage = hData[indexPath.row].image
            cell.message = hData[indexPath.row].message
        case 8:
            cell.itemImage = iData[indexPath.row].image
            cell.message = iData[indexPath.row].message
        case 9:
            cell.itemImage = jData[indexPath.row].image
            cell.message = jData[indexPath.row].message
        case 10:
            cell.itemImage = kData[indexPath.row].image
            cell.message = kData[indexPath.row].message
        case 11:
            cell.itemImage = lData[indexPath.row].image
            cell.message = lData[indexPath.row].message
        case 12:
            cell.itemImage = mData[indexPath.row].image
            cell.message = mData[indexPath.row].message
        case 13:
            cell.itemImage = nData[indexPath.row].image
            cell.message = nData[indexPath.row].message
        case 14:
            cell.itemImage = oData[indexPath.row].image
            cell.message = oData[indexPath.row].message
        case 15:
            cell.itemImage = pData[indexPath.row].image
            cell.message = pData[indexPath.row].message
        case 16:
            cell.itemImage = qData[indexPath.row].image
            cell.message = qData[indexPath.row].message
        case 17:
            cell.itemImage = rData[indexPath.row].image
            cell.message = rData[indexPath.row].message
        case 18:
            cell.itemImage = sData[indexPath.row].image
            cell.message = sData[indexPath.row].message
        case 19:
            cell.itemImage = tData[indexPath.row].image
            cell.message = tData[indexPath.row].message
        case 20:
            cell.itemImage = uData[indexPath.row].image
            cell.message = uData[indexPath.row].message
        case 21:
            cell.itemImage = vData[indexPath.row].image
            cell.message = vData[indexPath.row].message
        case 22:
            cell.itemImage = wData[indexPath.row].image
            cell.message = wData[indexPath.row].message
        case 23:
            cell.itemImage = xData[indexPath.row].image
            cell.message = xData[indexPath.row].message
        case 24:
            cell.itemImage = yData[indexPath.row].image
            cell.message = yData[indexPath.row].message
        default:
            cell.itemImage = zData[indexPath.row].image
            cell.message = zData[indexPath.row].message
        }

        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return rowHeight
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 26
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 {
            return aData.count
        }
        if section == 1 {
            return bData.count
        }
        if section == 2 {
            return cData.count
        }
        if section == 3 {
            return dData.count
        }
        if section == 4 {
            return eData.count
        }
        if section == 5 {
            return fData.count
        }
        if section == 6 {
            return gData.count
        }
        if section == 7 {
            return hData.count
        }
        if section == 8 {
            return iData.count
        }
        if section == 9 {
            return jData.count
        }
        if section == 10 {
            return kData.count
        }
        if section == 11 {
            return lData.count
        }
        if section == 12 {
            return mData.count
        }
        if section == 13 {
            return nData.count
        }
        if section == 14 {
            return oData.count
        }
        if section == 15 {
            return pData.count
        }
        if section == 16 {
            return qData.count
        }
        if section == 17 {
            return rData.count
        }
        if section == 18{
            return sData.count
        }
        if section == 19 {
            return tData.count
        }
        if section == 20 {
            return uData.count
        }
        if section == 21 {
            return vData.count
        }
        if section == 22 {
            return wData.count
        }
        if section == 23 {
            return xData.count
        }
        if section == 24 {
            return yData.count
        }
        return zData.count
    }
}
```

Comment: When you were using a UITableViewController, the delegate and dataSource were set for you. Since you switched to a regular UIViewController, you need to set them. This is why there is no data in your tableView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not prefereed nor right to add child vcs to a tableController , as the content will scroll with the parent table as `view = tableView` inside tableController it could work but it needs some a tweak inside `scrollViewDidScroll`  , so it's better to add it to a regular vc and add the table as a property

Comment: So I made an changed it to a regular view controller and added an extension of tableViewDelegate and tableViewDataSource. However, now I am seeing the tableView without any data in it. I am sure this is a basic mistake with implementing a tableView, but I was wondering if you could help me with this. I updated the code for the entire view controller above.

Answer (score 0):

Use ViewController for this and add tableview in between. This is the right approach to achieve this.